# WMI | Win32_ServerSession - Access denied

Tags: c#, wmi

I created this little C# win32 console application in visual studio by using the WMICodeCreator:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ServerSession"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_ServerSession instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("ActiveTime: {0}", queryObj["ActiveTime"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ClientType: {0}", queryObj["ClientType"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ComputerName: {0}", queryObj["ComputerName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("IdleTime: {0}", queryObj["IdleTime"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("InstallDate: {0}", queryObj["InstallDate"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ResourcesOpened: {0}", queryObj["ResourcesOpened"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("SessionType: {0}", queryObj["SessionType"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("TransportName: {0}", queryObj["TransportName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", queryObj["UserName"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get: **Access denied**. Even if I run it as administrator.

Why do I get "Access denied"?

Comment: Try this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: Did you try to include a manifest in your app? Could be the UAC?